# Exception in plugin WakaTime (14.2.3) when installing WakaTime on my IntelliJ IDEA 2019.9

Tags: jetbrains-ide, wakatime

[image]

This plugin is not a production of JetBrains.

Tried upgrading from jdk-11 to jdk-17, error persists.

Also, upgraded to IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2, still got an error.

Could a person use the WakaTime plugin concurrently on two tools: VSCode and IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: 1) You should only use the JDK that is bundled with the IDE. That's the best approach in those terms. 2) Check with the plugin author: https://github.com/wakatime/jetbrains-wakatime/issues . There was one ticket with a similar issue (as far as I can tell from the limited info available), but that was an older version and the issue is reported obsolete with the latest IDE and plugin versions. Anyway -- https://github.com/wakatime/jetbrains-wakatime/issues/255

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: Thank you @yacc for sharing this valuable insight, which I was previously unaware of no-no to image upload.

Comment: @LazyOne I have successfully resolved the issue by removing all instances of IntelliJ IDEA located in the 'bin' folder and subsequently reinstalling the latest version, which is version 2023.2. Thank you for your support.

Comment: @GeorgeOkumu Thanks for letting us know how you have managed to resolve your issue -- this can help other users in a similar situation. Cheers!